# import component selector into html with tags using visual studio code

Tags: html, angular, selector

I am facing difficulty importing angular components selector with tag into HTML using visual studio code. When I am writing the components selector name in HTML, it will give me the suggestions. However, after i press enter, it just input the selector without any tag in HTML. I would like to ask is there any configuration that can be done to include the selector with HTML?

Selector suggestions when I enter the selector name in HTML.
[image]

After I press enter, the selector appear without HTML tag
[image]

Comment: Where are you getting that suggestion from? Any extension?

Comment: Angular language service and angular snippets

Comment: Which is the editor?

Comment: visual studio code

Comment: VS code comes with [emmet abbreviation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet) by default. So when you type app-root, there will be a suggestion by emmet. Upon selecting that, you'll get the entire tag i.e `<app-root></app-root>`. So see if this has been accidently disabled in your editor.

Comment: After I keyed in app-root, I get the component suggestions. Then, I press enter. The editor show app-root without tag. I need to press ctrl + space, then emmet abbreviation appear, and I can get the tag after pressing the suggestions. I cannot get the tag for first time.